# Creating SQL Server (T-SQL) view that flattens nulls

Tags: sql-server, view, flatten

I'm having a lot of difficulty trying to create a view that flattens the data without nulls. I've supplied the code that creates two basic tables and my view code so you can see what I've tried so far. Please note that the two tables do not have a matching primary or foreign key column, so the summary in the view is created by just joining on City. I can't use XML because my team of data analysts all have intermediate skills and won't be able to understand it. I considered using a recursive CTE, but I can't get it right. The result produces 6 lines but I want 3 lines.
Thanks for any ideas about a better way to achieve this.

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    OrdID int,
    Cat varchar(255),
    Qty int,
    City varchar(255),
    Ctry varchar(255)
);
INSERT INTO A (OrdID, Cat, Qty, City, Ctry)
VALUES (1, 'TV', 5,'London',  'England');
INSERT INTO A (OrdID, Cat, Qty, City, Ctry)
VALUES (2, 'Laptop', 3,'London', 'England');
INSERT INTO A (OrdID, Cat, Qty, City, Ctry)
VALUES (3, 'Laptop', 4, 'Berlin', 'Germany');

CREATE TABLE Cust (
    CustID int,
    CustType varchar(255),
    City varchar(255),
    NumItems int,
);
INSERT INTO Cust (CustID, CustType, City, NumItems)
VALUES (1, 'New', 'London', 2);
INSERT INTO Cust (CustID, CustType, City, NumItems)
VALUES (2, 'Returning','London', 5);
INSERT INTO Cust (CustID, CustType, City, NumItems)
VALUES (3, 'Returning','Berlin', 2);
INSERT INTO Cust (CustID, CustType, City, NumItems)
VALUES (4, 'New','Berlin', 8);

alter view My_View
as

With CTE_FlattenNulls
as
(
Select 
S.Cat
, S.Qty
, S.City
, S.Ctry 
, case when C.CustType like 'New' then sum(C.NumItems) end as NewC
, case when C.CustType like 'Returning' then sum(C.NumItems) end as RetC
from A as S
left join Cust as C
on S.City = C.City
group by 
S.Cat
, S.Qty
, S.City
, S.Ctry
, C.CustType
)
select 
Cat
,Qty
,City
,Ctry
,NewC
,RetC
,SUM(IsNull(NewC, 0) + IsNull(RetC, 0)) as TotC
from CTE_FlattenNulls
group by
Cat
,Qty
,City
,Ctry
,NewC
,RetC

go
```

Just adding the output that I wanted:

| Cat | Qty | City | Cntry | NewC | RetCust | TotC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Laptop | 4 | Berlin | Germany | 8 | 2 | 10 |
| Laptop | 3 | London | England | 2 | 5 | 7 |
| TV | 5 | London | England | 2 | 5 | 7 |

Comment: Thanks Larnu for tidying the output example. I was Googling how to make it appear neater as it came out as one line of text.

Comment: It's not really "tidy" (I just popped it in a code fence to make it at least apparent it wasn't nonsense text), you have used inconsistent spacing rather than fixed width. A markdown table would be better, if I am honest.

Comment: To reduce number of rows you can reduce the number of non-aggergaring columns you specify in the select and group by clauses. So to get to 3 rows may mean you need max() or min() on some columns to help achieve the 3 rows.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell Good idea. I'll have a go at writing a subquery that returns the max() and min() values only and see where I can get to with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close.
See comments in code for explanation.

```
With CTE_FlattenNulls
as
(
Select S.Cat, S.Qty, S.City, S.Ctry,
    -- To do conditional summation case expression needs to be inside the SUM function
    sum( case when C.CustType like 'New' then C.NumItems else 0 end ) as NewC,
    sum( case when C.CustType like 'Returning' then C.NumItems else 0 end ) as RetC
from A as S
left join Cust as C
on S.City = C.City
group by 
S.Cat
, S.Qty
, S.City
, S.Ctry
-- then you do not need to group by this column and therefore you do not get extra rows
--, C.CustType 
)
select Cat, Qty, City, Ctry, NewC, RetC,
    -- As per your example, you would no longer need GROUP BY,
    --   therefore SUM function should be removed
    SUM(IsNull(NewC, 0) + IsNull(RetC, 0)) as TotC
from CTE_FlattenNulls
-- As per your example, you would no longer need GROUP BY
group by Cat, Qty, City, Ctry
-- ,NewC -- Definitely not needed anymore
-- ,RetC -- Definitely not needed anymore
```

Everything else stays the same

Comment: yes, that's perfect. That's exactly what I wanted to do. Do you mind if I just edit your answer to include the final line of the CTE otherwise beginners won't know why your doesn't run by itself.

Comment: @Only_me I still fail to see the need for a CTE to get to your requested results, is there a reason it must be done with a CTE ?

Comment: @GuidoG - I agree that in the example, as provided, there is no real need for a CTE but as OP mentioned the real code has more logic. CTEs should have no affect on performance. For the most part they are just syntax sugar (except recursive CTEs).

Answer (score 1):

To get to your result, why can you not just do a simple group by with conditional sum ?
It has no need for a CTE

See this example, also in [this DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e3b8bd5d4d3ac2876b5aa54a64609f9a)

```
select A.Cat,
       A.Qty,
       A.City,
       min(A.Ctry) as Country,
       sum(case when C.CustType = 'New' then C.NumItems else 0 end) as NewC,
       sum(case when C.CustType = 'Returning' then C.NumItems else 0 end) as RetCust,
       sum(C.NumItems) as TotC
from   A
  join Cust C on A.City = C.City
group by A.Cat,
         A.Qty,
         A.City
order by A.Cat, A.City
```

it returns this

| Cat | Qty | City | Country | NewC | RetCust | TotC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Laptop | 4 | Berlin | Germany | 8 | 2 | 10 |
| Laptop | 3 | London | England | 2 | 5 | 7 |
| TV | 5 | London | England | 2 | 5 | 7 |

Comment: Thanks very much GuidoG. That looks nice and concise and thanks for remembering my last Total column too. You're right, it doesn't need to use CTE, it was only that in the more complex version (real version) that I was trying to solve at work, there was more code and joins so I'd put it in CTE to keep it consistent with my work problem.

Comment: I can't see that complete real version off course, but even then you might still put the query without CTE in a subquery to avoid the use of CTE. I dont have anything against CTE but it just makes things a bit more complicated so I avoid them when not needed

Comment: Agreed - if it is not necessary to use CTE, then I'll try to write the code more simply. The view at work was already written by another data analyst and he used CTE to tidy up the joins and fields. It's one of those cases where I need to modify/update what he has already without rewriting everything he did and possibly offending his coding style by saying what I've done is better :) It's what he's comfortable using and reading.

Comment: Well it's all up to you, in this case the example code is small enough so the CTE does not makes things to hard to read at all, but as I said, I don't know how big and complicated your actual query is. If you have to change to much to get it without using cte then I understand that you would keep it off course